# How to create a click event on group object in sketchup?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have cubes in sketchup.each cube is grouped from four faces like this:

```
    entities = model.active_entities
    pts = []
    pts[0] = [0, 0, 0]
    pts[1] = [width, 0, 0]
    pts[2] = [width, depth, 0]
    pts[3] = [0, depth, 0]
    # Add the group to the entities in the model
    group = entities.add_group
```

this creates a box.now how can i create click event on that box so that when clicked on box.it shows Group.name in messagebox?

Comment: Why do you want the name popping up in a messagebox when it's displayed in Entity Info?

Comment: @thomthom because entity name field consists of a binid value which i want to query sql server  to get products in that bin and display in messagebox.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that you make a custom Query tool - I'll expand my answer somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SketchUp API doesn't let you do this outside of a custom Tool: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/tool

Edit: Seeing how you are querying the group name in a database then a custom query tool is the way to go. When your user activate your tool you have mouse and key events like `onLButtonDown` and `OnLButtonUp`. These event provide the `x` and `y` coordinate of where mouse is on the SketchUp viewport.

Then you can use the `PickHelper` class to find what entity the user picked: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/pickhelper
Most of the time you want to simply use the `best_picked` after doing your pick with `do_pick`. `best_picked` will return an entity which you can check if it's a group or component. This entity will be the same as what the Select tool would select.

<strike>The only generic way outside of a custom tool would perhaps to user an `SelectionObserver` to detect when your group is selected. But I'd discourage against this as it's so easy that this will just interfere with the normal usage of SketchUp.</strike>